# CSS3 animation reset

Tags: jquery, animation, css

I have a question about CSS3. Is there an option to reset the animation after it finish (for example by using jQuery)?

Example: after button click, animation reset.

Comment: How are you creating the animation? with css3 `transition` or with jquery `.animate()`?

Comment: css3 animations: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 8):

I found better solution:

```
$('something').removeClass('anim').animate({'nothing':null}, 1, function () {
$(this).addClass('anim');
});
```

It's working. Ofc it need a css class '.anim' with the animation.

Answer (score -1):

This question is old, but i figured out a nice way to restart a css3 animation with jQuery while i was working on a project, and now i want to share. here is the trick:

```
$('#anim-div').replaceWith($('#anim-div'));
```

and this will restart the animation on '#anim-div', it works.